# Ante and Blinds

Tags: blinds

I am familiar with antes as well as blinds but after doing some reading I've seen that sometimes there are both (surprise!)  Been trying to search for more info but can't find any.

So, in a game with both... Do all players pay the ante while SB/BB pay their amounts or does SB/BB also pay additional ante amount?

Comment: Technically speaking blinds are antes. The term Ante is used in Nevada legal code when defining blinds. I believe the word Ante has its roots in Spanish and means "first" so anything that is bet before cards are dealt is an ante rather it is a conventional bet like we call blind or a simple sweetener for the pot that everyone pays that we call ante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ante is in before the blinds, it is paid by every player and usually set at about 12% of the big blind, in some games the button will pay all the antes at once instead of every player paying it to save the dealer some effort, when this happens the player who paid all the antes still has to pay the blinds to see a hand

Answer (score 2):

in a game with blinds and antes, all players pay the antes and the blinds put out their blinds after they have paid the ante.